# DataTables doesn't work when <script>'s are placed at the end of file

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/).

I am using the below code, but DataTables doesn't seem to initialize. I can move the `<script>`'s to the top of the document and it works then but I understood that it is better to have these at the bottom of the document.

Is there a reason for it not working when I move these to the bottom of the document. I think I am loading them in the correct order etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>
      Test
    </title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                        "url": "server_processing/test.php",
                        "type": "POST"
                        },
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 id="tables">Test</h1>
      </div>

      <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Invoice No</th>
                  <th>Order No</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>  

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $('#example')
               .removeClass( 'display' )
               .addClass('table table-bordered');
      </script>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why is it better to have the at the bottom?

Comment: People usually regurgitate that it's better to have scripts at the bottom of the page but usually they use that as a catch-all solution to them not properly understanding what they are doing. The only thing that matters is that your scripts can reference what they are trying to reference when they are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the script tags at bottom of body, you also need to place any dependent code after those script tags.

You are currently trying to compile code that depends on jQuery, before the jQuery library is loaded.

Place all of your own code after the external file tags

Answer (score 0):

The script file declarations need to come before the code that is referencing them.

Consider the following format, which I use for all of my projects:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Testing Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="example">
        Blah blah blah
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //do all of your jQuery/Datatables stuff in here
    alert('Woo hoo!');

});
/*]]>*/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```